# Given an array of objects how can I merge Objects within the array based of the keys?

Tags: javascript

If the following array is given as an example , I would want the function to compare the key for each object, if It is the same merge them to the new Object.

For the inner Object( team's value) if the keys match and One's value is OWNER keep this and disregard Member otherwise keep Member.

```
var array= [{team1 : {tim : OWNER, joe : MEMBER,jane : MEMBER}}, 
        {team1 : {bob : MEMBER, joe : OWNER}},
        {team2 : {bob : OWNER, tim : OWNER}}]

Return newTeam1= {tim : Owner, Joe:Owner , Jane : Member}
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Also it is not a valid object literal

Comment: It's a little hard to understand how to help on this because your example code isn't valid javascript. Can you edit the thing you're given to make it something that doesn't throw errors.

Comment: I have been able to take care of the inner object requirement , I am having trouble comparing the key within the same list.

Comment: what happened to bob ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to conditionally reduce the teams into an object with labels for each team. Members with conflicting names will resolve into a key of `"OWNER"` in the final output.

Also, in your result for `"team1"`, I've included Bob from the second instance of `"team1"`, but you can drop him by removing `!(member in a[team]) ||`. This will ignore new members from subsequent teams after the first unless they have a name conflict with the first and are an `"OWNER"`.

```js
var array = [{team1:{tim:"OWNER", joe:"MEMBER",jane:"MEMBER"}}, 
             {team1:{bob:"MEMBER", joe:"OWNER"}},
             {team2:{bob:"OWNER", tim:"OWNER"}}];

console.log(array.reduce((a, o) => {
  for (const team in o) {
    if (team in a) {
      for (const member in o[team]) {
        if (!(member in a[team]) || a[team][member] === "MEMBER") {
          a[team][member] = o[team][member];
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      a[team] = o[team];
    }
  }
  
  return a;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of popular libraries that support deep merge :

```js
var array = [{team1 : {tim : 'OWNER' , joe : 'MEMBER', jane: 'MEMBER'}}, 
             {team1 : {bob : 'MEMBER', joe : 'OWNER'}},
             {team2 : {bob : 'OWNER' , tim : 'OWNER'}}]

console.log( _.merge({}, ...array) )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```